# count rolling changes in singular column by ID and Week Number

Tags: python, pandas

been trying to work on this problem for the last few hours with no luck.

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
id = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
weeks = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
contr = [16,16,22,37,37,16]


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : id,
             'Week' : weeks,
             'Contract' : contr})

print(df)
   ID  Week Contract
0   1   1   16
1   1   2   16
2   1   3   22
3   2   1   37
4   2   2   37
5   2   3   16
```

now what I'm trying to do is count the number of changes for a contract by ID in a given week (my df is small, around 1.8 million rows)

so what I thought *could* work was to do a rolling count of a value which isn't equal to the one above of which I've tried by playing around with this code :

```
df['count'] = df['ID'].groupby((df['Contract'] != df['Contract'].shift(-1)).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

but this is not giving me the desired result,

what I'm after is something like the following

```
    print(df)
   ID  Week Contract count
0   1   1   16       0   # First instance is this is ignored 
1   1   2   16       0   # No Change so 0
2   1   3   22       1   # Change here so 1
3   2   1   37       0
4   2   2   37       0
5   2   3   16       1
6   2   4   16       0  # This should be 0 as the change was in the prev Week
```

(if this doesn't meet a minimal question please let me know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `diff` to get the value change or not , then we need another `groupby` to `cumsum` by `ID`

```
s=df.groupby('ID').Contract.diff().ne(0)
s.groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()-1
Out[33]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
Name: Contract, dtype: float64
df['Count']=s.groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()-1
```

Comment: awesome, this works!, only downside (this is my fault nothing to do with you) is that the consecutive changes are also listed with a 1, would there be a way to list these as a 0 with this line of code?

Comment: @Datanovice would you like show to us in your sample data and your expected output ? I think I can fix it

Comment: Made a slight edit to the expected output, with the code I've used above I get a 1 where in the final output I'd like a 0. If not it's fine I can work around it

Comment: @Datanovice I made a mistake paste wrong one `(s.groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()-1).mask(df.duplicated(['ID','Contract']),0)
`

Comment: you are an absolute genius. Thank you Wen!

Comment: @Datanovice happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using apply:

```
df['Count']=df.groupby('ID')['Contract'].apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).cumsum()-1)
#or df.groupby('ID')['Contract'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
print(df)

   ID  Week  Contract  Count
0   1     1        16      0
1   1     2        16      0
2   1     3        22      1
3   2     1        37      0
4   2     2        37      0
5   2     3        16      1
```

Comment: Thanks Anky, tested this and it works the same as Wen's!